# jBoss7 no remote access

Tags: linux, jboss, jboss7.x

i setup a jboss7 server including the standalon.xml for remote access on a debian machine.
But I cant get external remote access.

This is my interface part of the standalone.xml:

```
<interfaces>
   <interface name="management">
       <inet-address value="192.168.3.182"/>
   </interface>
   <interface name="public">
       <inet-address value="192.168.3.182"/>
   </interface>
</interfaces>
```

I also tried:

```
<interfaces>
   <interface name="management">
      <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
   </interface>
   <interface name="public">
      <any-ipv4-address/>
   </interface>
</interfaces>
```

I tried a lot of possibilities to setting up the standalone.xml but I must forgot something.

I see the jboss7 homepage when I type the ip address in my browser but Im note able to connect with my java test client on the remote port(4447).

The test client works if the client runs local on the machine.

Do you have an idea?

Edit: telnet 192.168.3.182 4447 gives me the ip back with a blink cursor, so i guess waiting for response additional i see a log entry in my jboss server log -> ) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1728579688

Comment: looks more like a networking problem to me. Is the Debian box protected by a firewall?

Comment: i thought that too......but there is no firewall and we had jboss4 running before on this server and that worked.

Comment: Just to double-check: client connecting 4447 from local machine works, from remote machine not, correct? What does `netstat -an | grep 4447` output?

Comment: tcp        0      0 192.168.3.182:4447      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: And what happens when you `telnet 192.168.3.182 4447` from remote? Refusing connection? Waiting w/o response? Maybe editing question is more efficient than adding comment.

Comment: OK. This means it is not a network problem. Maybe your client uses wrong credentials? I'm afraid I cannot help you any further :(

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the port is listening with the following command under linux "netstat -tulpn | grep -i 4447"

Good luck,

Comment: thats the result

tcp        0      0 192.168.3.182:4447      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26679/java

so it seems to be working

Comment: Hi @kclair , I tried to add all the jars mentioned in the blog, but no luck. Do you have anymore insight on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

that "Received an invalid message length of 1728579688" error indicates that jboss is listening on the port but that the connector is not using the right kind of protocol.

of course, if you are connecting with telnet then you would expect to see that error since telnet is not a JMX client.

JBoss uses JBoss Remoting for JMX connections.  So if you are using an external client, you need to make sure the JBoss Remoting libraries are available to your client.

This is a good description of the issue using VisualVM as the client:

http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/11/01/connecting-visualvm-with-a-remote-jboss-as-7-eap6-jvm-process/